# Jenkins: Command "git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree"

Tags: git, jenkins, ubuntu-13.10

I built .git in the workspace already but when tried to build my project but got this error.

I use Ubuntu, Jenkins,and Git plugin 2.0.4.

```
Building in workspace /home/xxxx/Desktop/Jenkins
ERROR: Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt.
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1160)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1156)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:972)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:982)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.hasGitRepo(CliGitAPIImpl.java:136)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.hasGitRepo(GitAPI.java:186)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:830)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:878)
...
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git
ERROR: Failed to clean the workspace
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/xxxx/Desktop/Jenkins/.git
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
```

Comment: Given that you're getting Access Denied exceptions, perhaps the owner of the directory isn't one that Jenkins has access to?

Comment: Thanks! @Amber 
The permission was 775 then I changed to 777 it solved